# Can I change the universal image loader SDcard cache key??Emergency

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

As my image Uri uses a different way to make sure the App pivture is safe.
It changes everytime when I request. For example, it may be like [this](http://youyou.qiniudn.com/ff6158ca2330b0?e=1376038933&token=2xD9fSrurwz0o0YpXNXUmRwpwnXcXYZsr4MnLd7f:i3-XdQtwFWIVn1c-0r5xgIhQuvE=)

and next time it comes like [this](http://youyou.qiniudn.com/ff6158ca2330b0e=1376038933&token=2xD9fSrurwz0o0YpXNXUmRwpwnXcXYZsr4MnLd7f:ZHKI4KfDL_snisR_UxZcACz8ICE=)

As universal image loader uses the Uri as key for SD Chche .
The image Uri changes for the end of the Uri
I want to use only [this](http://youyou.qiniudn.com/ff6158ca2330b0) part as key
I searched for a long time but still don`t get the answer.
So please help me

Comment: alex posted right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is pretty simple to change. Nostra's universal image loader uses a interface "[FileNameGenerator](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/cache/disc/naming/FileNameGenerator.java)" with the method "generate" in com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.naming; Just create or adapt a class there and use this for your purpose. E.g. change HashCodeFileNameGenerator to:

```
 public class HashCodeFileNameGenerator implements FileNameGenerator {
@Override
public String generate(String imageUri) {
    return String.valueOf(imageUri.substr(0, imageUri.indexOf("=")).hashCode());
}
 }
```

The code above would generate a filename based on the image url till the first occurence of the sign '='.

Comment: Wow thks man~!It works !ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
    getApplicationContext())
    .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())//your FileNameGenerator
    
    .build();  Thanks again!

Comment: Can you please mark the topic as solved with the green apply button on the left?

Comment: I am very new here sorry~!I will do it